# How to manually manage Hibernate sessions in @PostContruct methods?

Tags: spring, hibernate, lazy-loading

My problem is straightforward. I want to access some data from the database when the application loads on Tomcat. To do something at that point in time I use @PostConstruct (which does its job properly).

However, in that method I make 2 separate connections to the DB: one for bringing a list of entities and another for adding them into a common library. The second step implies some behind-the-scenes queries for resolving some lazy-loading associations. Here is the code snippet:

```
@Override
@PostConstruct
public void populateLibrary() {
// query for the Book Descriptors - 1st query works!!!
List<BookDescriptor> bookDescriptors= bookDescriptorService.list();

Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction transaction = null;
try {
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        // resolving some lazy-loading associations - 2nd query fails!!!
    for (BookDescriptor book: bookDescriptors) {
         library.addEntry(book);
    }

    transaction.commit();
} catch (HibernateException e) {

    transaction.rollback();
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    session.close();
}
}
```

1st query works while the 2nd fails, as I wrote in the comments. The failure gives:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:86)
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:140)
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:190)
at com.freightgate.domain.SecurityFiling_$$_javassist_7.getSfSubmissionType(SecurityFiling_$$_javassist_7.java)
at com.freightgate.dao.SecurityFilingTest.test(SecurityFilingTest.java:73)
```

Which is very odd since I explicitly opened and closed a transaction. However, if I inspect some details of *how* the 1st query works it seems like behind the scenes the session is bound to AbstractLazyInitializer class.

I resolved my problem by abstracting away the functionality from the for loop into a separate service class that is annotated with @Transactional(readOnly = true). Still I'm puzzled as to why the approch that I posted here fails.

If anyone has some hints, I'd be very happy to hear them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You load entities in a first session, then close this session, then open a new session, and try to lazy-load collections of the entities. That can't work.

For lazy-loading to work, the entity must be attached to an open session. Just opening another session doesn't make any entity you have loaded before attached to this new session. In the meantime, some other transaction could have radically changed the database, the entity could not exist anymore...

The best solution is what you have done. Encapsulate evrything into a single transactional service. You could also have open the transaction before calling the first service, but why handle transactions programmatically, since Spring does it for you declaratively?